# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c'

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-8

I have a problem.
I've installed last secure PHP 8.0.1, Laravel through Composer. Updated Composer to 2.0.9. And now every php/composer command continues with warnings like this:

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c'`

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird'`

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci'`

And my project on the welcome.blade.php says:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the oci8 and pdo_oci errors, start by installing the Oracle Instant Client 'Basic' package as shown in the PHP manual, or shown on the relevant operating system [Instant Client Download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  I'm assuming you want to use Oracle.